# How do I automatically turn a URL I input into a cell into a hyperlinked text in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Please see image for reference. I want the cell to always read "Link" in columns B through E whenever any URL is posted in those cells. I was told this needs to be an Apps Script; however, I'm not exactly sure on how to go about doing this.

So as an example: I post a random URL, randomURL1.com, in cell B3 I want it to automatically change that to read "Link" and be a clickable text.

Thanks!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYKbs.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When an URL is put to a cell, you want to convert the URL to a text which has a hyperlink of the URL.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and please set the sheet name. And, please save the script. When you use this script, please put an URL to a cell. By this, the URL is converted to a text of "Link" with the hyperlink.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const { range } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const value = range.getValue();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName || !value.match(/^https?:\/\/.+/)) return;
  const r = range.getRichTextValue().copy().setText("Link").setLinkUrl(value).build();
  range.setRichTextValue(r);
}
```

- For example, when an URL like `https://sample.com` is put to a cell, this script is run and a text of "Link" with the URL is put to the cell.
- In this script, RichText is used. If you want to use a formula of `HYPERLINK`, please modify as follows.

  - From

    ```
      const r = range.getRichTextValue().copy().setText("Link").setLinkUrl(value).build();
      range.setRichTextValue(r);
    ```
  - To

    ```
      range.setFormula(`=HYPERLINK("${value}","Link")`);
    ```
- In this script, in order to check the URL, `http://` or `https://` are checked. So, please put the URL including `http://` or `https://`.

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Class RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)
- [setFormula(formula)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)

Comment: Amazing job, that solved the issue!

Comment: Done, thanks! I did have another question regarding a different script, but I'll ask it in another post.

Comment: @ScriptSalad Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Comment: I hope it isn't too much of a bother, but would you be able to take a look at my other query to see if it is something you are familiar with? Thank you!

Comment: @ScriptSalad About your new question of `but would you be able to take a look at my other query to see if it is something you are familiar with?`, I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your new question. If you have new questions, I would like to recommend posting it as new question by including more information. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill. If you can cooperate to resolve your new question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Your English is perfect, I will repost it with more clarity and let you know.

Comment: I have posted my new question on my profile. Thank you!